# MatLab matrix construction

Tags: matlab, matrix

If I construct the matrix `A1` as follow:

```
a1=2; 
v1i=0;
t1i=0; 
dt=0.1; 
syms t real 
t1f=solve(int(a1,t)+v1i==40,t); 
t1=t1i:dt:t1f;
A1(:,1)=t1;
A1(:,2)=a1;
```

then `A1` is displayed as:

```
[      0, 2]
[   1/10, 2]
[    1/5, 2]
[   3/10, 2]
...
```

However, I want `A1` to be like this:

```
   0    2.0000
0.1000    2.0000
0.2000    2.0000
0.3000    2.0000
...
```

After a bit playing with this, I noticed that `t1f` and perhaps how it is calculated effects the shape of the matrix. So

```
a1=2;  
v1i=0;
t1i=0; 
dt=0.1; 
t1=t1i:dt:20;
A1(:,1)=t1;
A1(:,2)=a1;
```

produces the desired result. How can I get my desired matrix shape without removing the calculation for `t1f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) solution, you can perform the solution numerically and avoid the Symbolic Toolbox altogether:

```
t1f = fzero(@(t) integral(@(t)a1,0,t,'ArrayValued',true)+v1i-40,v1i);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that I found an answer. `t1f` is a `sym` so if I make it `double`, then I get my desired result:

```
a1=2; 
v1i=0;
t1i=0; 
dt=0.1; 
syms t real 
t1f=double(solve(int(a1,t)+v1i==40,t)); 
t1=t1i:dt:t1f;
A1(:,1)=t1;
A1(:,2)=a1;
```